# URL-Encoding issue using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a string "Urząd" with polish characters. I need convert string to ISO-8859-2 format using JMeter(Groovy or Beanshel). Expected value after conversion is Urz%B1d.

We have URLEncoder.encode('Urząd','ISO-8859-2') which works with Jmeter 5.5.
I need to use JMeter5.4.1. Can anyone share similar solution @JMeter5.4.1.?

Appreciate if anyone can help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JMeter version matters because it's mainly being handled by the underlying [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) libraries:

[image]

Just in case correct [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) syntax:

```
${__groovy(URLEncoder.encode('Urząd'\,'ISO-8859-2'),)}
```

If the above function doesn't work for you - check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

With regards to JMeter 5.4.1 I don't think it's a good idea to use it because this JMeter version has [major security vulnerability](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-45105). Moreover [it's recommended to use latest JMeter version](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling#use) as they have not only new features but also performance improvements and bug fixes